# Building a HTTP request with varying number of arguments?

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to write a node function that will build a URL from the arguments passed to it, and then use `request.js` to make a HTTP GET.

I can't figure out how best to deal with the fact that the URL will be valid as long as one argument is present. Take my function as

```
track = function(company, employee, app) {
  var url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/?"+"company="+company+"&app="+app+"&employee="+employee;
  request(url, function (error, response, body) {
  })
};
```

so if I called it with all 3 parameters the resultant URL would be valid and processed by my server

```
track("google", "larry", "chrome")
http://127.0.0.1:8000/?company=google&app=larry&employee=chrome
```

all possible URLs arising from combinations of 1/2/3 of these parameters would all be valid too

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/?company=google
http://127.0.0.1:8000/?company=google&app=chrome
http://127.0.0.1:8000/?employee=larry
```

As it is stands, if I only wanted to send a track request for `employee=larry` and called the function via `track("larry")` the URL would be

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/?company=larry&app=undefined&employee=undefined
```

How then do I write my function to allow for different permutations of arguments? I know I could do a check for the existence of each parameters and have if/else conditions for each permutation, but I'm looking for a more efficient approach.

Comment: Pass them as an object and iterate over its properties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass in an object rather than a list of separate parameters.

```
function track(params) {
    var url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/?'
    var arr = [];
    for (var p in params) {
        arr.push(p + '=' + params[p]);
    }
    request(url + arr.join('&'), function (err, res, body) { //... });
}

track({
    name: 'Larry',
    company: 'Google'
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3pk0hv6z/)

Comment: @JeremyThille omitting the arguments from a function header greatly obfuscates the code's readability.

Comment: You would still need to check, before adding each property, that the value is assigned. Otherwise you would end up with the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

Ultimately you can't have fixed parameters, omit them, and expect the function to know how to deal with that. There are only really 2 ways of doing what you want

- Pass the parameters *mapped* (e.g. passing as an object, `arguments`)
- Pass `null` (or some other default value) for the parameters you want to omit

Keeping with the fixed parameter approach, you could build up an array and then use `join` to give you a nice query string

```
var params = [];
if (company) {
    params.push("company=" + company);
}
if (employee) {
    params.push("employee=" + employee);
}
if (app) {
    params.push("app=" + app);
}
var url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/?" + params.join("&");
...
track("google", "larry", "chrome");
track("google", null, "chrome");
track(null, "larry", null);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5cj9psoc/)